# Turning off mobile data: method used to work but now doesn't

Tags: mobile-data

On my old phone I used to turn on mobile data when I wanted to check emails... but I would often forget to turn it off afterwards. To fix this problem I installed [Macrodroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid&hl=en_GB) and programmed it to turn off mobile data every time the screen turned off. This was my perfect solution and was very happy with it for years.

Now I have a newer phone (Android 5.0.1) and was very sad to see that with this version of android it appears that Macrodroid can no longer turn off mobile data. This now means that when I occasionally forget to turn it off manually I can use up a ton of data. Now you might say "no worries, just set a mobile data limit" - but this does not solve the problem at all - it may mean that I won't go over my limit but that's of little comfort when it means that I have used up all my data and can not use it again till the next billing period.

Is there any other way to manage my forgetfulness?

By the way I know that macrodroid can control mobile data if the phone is rooted - but my banking app, which I use regularly, detects a rooted phone and refuses to run.

Comment: In Kit Kat you didn't need root to do that. In Lollipop and above you need root. That's the way OS changed. Of you want this feature badly, you need to root or as I heard you can use apps like Automateit to mimic switching off data. There is no other way.. it's not the fault of Automation app. BTW, I use same app on MM for the same purpose being rooted

Comment: Some folks in Reddit's [Tasker community](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/) managed to use AutoInput app to toggle mobile data without the need of root.

Comment: @Firelord Rightly so tested it on my device (running Android 4 though)

Comment: @xavier_fakerat Perhaps you can provide more pointers through an answer? If answer doesn't work out well you can always take it down you know. :D

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to toggle mobile data **without root**, using Tasker and [AutoInput plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput&hl=en).

**Important**: This feature requires screen to be on.
(Some users report that it only works if screen lock security is set to none or swipe.)

You need to perform two tasks as follows:

- A1: Go to new action >> Plugin >> AutoInput >> Unlock screen
- A2: Net >> Mobile data >> [Set Off or toggle (whatever you wish)]
- Exit to save Task

**Note**: AutoInput also  emulates user swipes on the screen, which means that you can pull down the notification menu and then toggle whatever you want, including mobile data.

Create a condition/profile that suits your needs.

*Tested on Android 4*

Acknowledgements: 
[New to Tasker: toggle Mobile Data + GPS on non-rooted device](https://forum.xda-developers.com/u/tasker-tips-tricks/to-tasker-toggle-mobile-data-gps-rooted-t3423495)

Comment: The problem here is that the mobile data on/off on my phone is a toggle - which means that I can only automate the task of toggling mobile data... but what if it happened to be off in the first place - this automated task will now switch it on :-(

Comment: You mean you can't explicity turn off mobile data in tasker? if that the case then your issue is a bit complicated. How about using root, then hide your banking app with roatcloak or magisk?

Comment: rootcloak has poor reviews - there was even one review suggesting that it did not work for the banking app of my specific bank. I could not find magisk but presume that root cloaking is inherently unreliable.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the relevant extracts to automate data on/off using AutoInput:

> Here's the exported descriptions for enabling & disabling mobile data.
>
> **Turn On Data**
>
> A1: Popup [ Title: Text:Turning on data Background Image: Layout:Popup
>   Timeout (Seconds):1 Show Over Keyguard:On ]
>
> A2: AutoInput Global Action [ Configuration:Action: Quick Settings
>   Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
>
> A3: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text Value: Mobile data
>   Action : Click Is Tasker Action: false Check Screen State: false
>   Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
>
> A4: AutoInput Global Action [ Configuration:Action: Back Timeout
>   (Seconds):20 ]
>
> **Turn Off Data**
>
> A1: Popup [ Title: Text:Turning off data Background Image:
>   Layout:Popup Timeout (Seconds):1 Show Over Keyguard:On ]
>
> A2: AutoInput Global Action [ Configuration:Action: Quick Settings
>   Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
>
> A3: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text Value: Mobile data
>   Action : Click Is Tasker Action: false Check Screen State: false
>   Timeout (Seconds):20 ]
>
> A4: AutoInput Action [ Configuration:Type: Text Value: TURN OFF Action
>   : Click Is Tasker Action: false Check Screen State: false Timeout
>   (Seconds):20 ]

Source: [Disable Mobile Data Pop-Up (Android 6.0.1)](https://www.reddit.com/r/tasker/comments/4ykk9o/disable_mobile_data_popup_android_601/)

Comment: @Mick did you try using this method?